# permission denial in android studio

Tags: java, android

I want to create an android application which view phone contact in application and I wrote this code in my activity

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, 1);
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS}, 1);
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 1);
        }
Uri u = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
Cursor curs = getContentResolver().query(u, null, null, null, null);
btn_some.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showContacts();
            }
        });
```

this code works fine with emulator but when I tried it on my phone it has stopped
logcat message is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.MyApplication/com.example.MyApplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{5b66da3 28379:com.example.MyApplication/u0a264} (pid=28379, uid=10264) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
```

and this is my Mainfest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
```

How can I run this application on my phone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add permission to the manifest.xml file:

[image]

Comment: it's already exist in it
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>

Comment: Please take a deep look to the https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names#java

Comment: okay now it's worked but when I open application for first time it stopped again and then I get permission message on my phone when I accept all permission application run correctly so can I solve that ?

Comment: It is worked after accepting permissions, and what did it say when stops?

Comment: the same error message in logcat which I mentioned in question

Comment: I want to make application run correctly then ask me for all permissions

Comment: Thanks a lot I resolved this issue by override onActivityResult method and application run correctly